# What is your development workflow when it comes to Azure Devops Pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I've googling this, and I'm not sure it I use the right keywords or not, but I couldn't find what I was actually looking for.

Fair warning I'm quite green when it comes to Devops, so my question might seems stupid, but I'm ready to face your judgments :)

So I need to create a new pipeline for my project, and one of the things that I really dislike when I have to this, is the complexity of the workflow:

1. Create the yml file on my computer
2. Make the first commit
3. Push the modifications
4. Go to Azure and create the pipeline
5. Try to run it, it fails
6. Edit the file, push, try, find errors
7. Go back to step 6.

When I do this it really feels like I'm testing on production, and it's pretty cumbersome also.

So I was wondering if there was an easier/more efficient way to work on Azure pipeline.

Thanks for all your support and consideration :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I have found the portal is the best way to edit YAML pipelines. It's unfortunate as I haven't come across any good editors. Once you are proficient in it can leverage VS Code; however, even then the detail errors in the portal indicating line number, etc.. is really nice.

One thing to consider once you have a stable pipeline is to branch and update your pipeline off the branch. You can choose which version of the pipeline to execute when manually trigging the pipeline.

When just getting started with YAML pipelines I have found the below blog series helpful https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/healthcare-and-life-sciences/bg-p/HealthcareAndLifeSciencesBlog/label-name/YAML%20Pipeline%20Series

Answer (score 0):

So,

I looked further into it and for now what I'm settling with with is as follow:

1. Create the pipeline file in a separated branch
2. Create the pipeline on ADO setting the starting file as the one you just pushed
3. Edit the file on the online editor
4. Save on the online editor
5. Use the Azure CLI to start the run: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/pipelines?view=azure-cli-latest#az-pipelines-run

This new workflow helps, because the `az pipelines run` command can open the result page for you directly.

One of the thing that would drive me crazy is the lost time for going back to the edition of your pipeline once it's done. (Your on the online file editor, you can save and run, if you take this option, then your current page directly goes to the result page, and then you have to navigate back to your pipeline edition, which when you're in the developing phase, will happen pretty often and was pretty annoying to me.)

So running from the command line allows you to keep your browser open on your file edition. So when the execution is done, just move back to your edition tab and continue whatever you were doing.

Another perk of this method is that the command line let you set parameters and variables of your pipeline directly, so no need to open the "Variables" panel to whatever you want to set before your run.

I had to concede the use of a local file editor as it would have implied to git add/commit/push for every modification I'd do. As when using the online editor, sums up to "Save"

I'm not sure this is going to help anyone, as I didn't find anything on this subject online, so either I'm first one asking this question (highly improbable) either no one cares :)

Happy codding everyone.